# how can i cut a list and reverse the two halves?

Tags: python, list, slice

For example, if I input a function that takes a list, and an index, how can i code it so it returns a list cut in half and swapped positions using loops

```
function([0,1,2,3,4], 2)
```

returns

```
[3, 4, 2, 0, 1]
```

I've tried:

```
def function(list_value):
    first_half = list_value[:index] 
    second_half = list_value[(index+1):] 
    swapped_sequence = second_half + first_half 
    swapped_sequence = swapped_sequence.insert(index, index) 
    return swapped_sequence
```

Comment: Why isn't 2 reversed?

Comment: What have to tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: first_half = list_value[:index]
    second_half = list_value[(index+1):]
    swapped_sequence = second_half + first_half
    swapped_sequence = swapped_sequence.insert(index, index)
    return swapped_sequence

Comment: @DaquarisGeorgino This seems to be a reasonably solution to the question asked Please update with current and expected output?

Comment: Your output list isn't cut in half.

Comment: Sorry, I mean't cut at index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic version, just use list indexing and join 3 the parts.

```
def cut(x, i):
    try:
        return x[i + 1:] + x[i:i + 1] + x[:i]  
    except IndexError:  
        return []
```

Comment: I may be wrong, and for this example it doesn't affect performance, but accessing a slice is O(k) complexity, while getting an element is O(1) and appending an element is O(1), so wouldn't simply looking up the middle element be more efficient?

Comment: @chris What would you do once you look up the middle element? Also, I'd imagine appending is linear, because of the space allocation unfortunately.

Comment: Append is an O(1) operation.  I was just imaging replacing `x[i: i + 1]` with `[x[i]]`.  However, the finally concatenation bounds the runtime at O(n) anyway, which is the worst case of slice lookup, so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Using slices: `713 ns ± 5.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`. Using lookups: `640 ns ± 13.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Answer (score 0):

Although not faster we can use np.roll:

```
import numpy as np

def function(lst,ind):
    roll = np.roll(lst, ind)[:-1]
    lst_n = np.insert(roll, ind, ind)
    return lst_n

function([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 2)
```